# DIV's isn't flowing normally

Tags: css, css-position

I have a problem with positioning div classes like normally it would be.
I wanted to get the DIV boxes:

```
li {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    position:relative;
}

li div {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

But then the boxes are like positioned absolutely, they aren't as I wanted to get them - in 2 columns, with gap of 20px and gap underneath of 50px, but they're stuck like they would be in-lined, but with 20px margin-right, which, as I see, is calculated, starting with the left border of image, but margin-bottom is ok.

Then I just got mad and copied all the code, that was in TutsPlus.com - CSS3 Essentials video - still not working.
With HTML5 all is ok, but I don't get it - why I couldn't get that boxes like I said before?

Comment: Did you try adding `display: block;` to the lis?

Comment: Please show a mockup of the desired result. A jsFiddle wouldn't hurt, too!

Comment: I do found the solution already. If there will be other prob's, I'll write it here or, probably, somewhere other place.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow by default. You set them to a width of 100% so they will be as wide as the li and overlap each other.

Comment: Neither of your suggestions helped me.
Problem was, when the width and height didn't applied on image, which was the front picture of box.
Changed sizes manually, but thanks to both of you.

Comment: My answer was not a suggestion but pointing to why your markup isn't working. I can't give you a fix without seeing the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that it the `<li>`s are not in two columns, you could make the `<ul>` have a width of `440px` (which is `200 + 20 px` (width of the `<li>` with margin) multiplited by two). Basically:

```
ul {
    width: 440px
    }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pKQtU/1)